# C#, Unable to retrieve 'Request.UserHostAddress' from HttpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, ip-address

I am working on an MVC project in C# using dotnet version 2.2.107. I am trying to retrieve the remote IP address of the client using the **UserHostAddress** property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress?view=netframework-4.8

I have included **System.Web** and **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http** dependencies and I am trying to run this line:

`string userHostAddress = Request.UserHostAddress;`

Still, I am receiving the following error message:

*'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'UserHostAddress' and no accessible extension method 'UserHostAddress' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

I have also tried retrieving with **ServerVariables** and **HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress** but these aren't working.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpConnectionFeature>()?.RemoteIpAddress